# Cabinet Fan is making a lot of noise

Tags: cpu, fan, noise

The Fan attached to my CPU cabinet is making a lot of noise especially when I switch on my PC in the morning. The screws on them are not too tight nor are they too loose. This ridiculous chainsaw like sound is driving me crazy. Please HELP !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fans generally fail eventually; the moving parts wear out or become contaminated with dust. Most likely the solution will be to replace the fan.

Other possible solutions:

- Check for cables or other loose items dangling in the path of the fan blades; zip-tie them back.
- You can try blowing the dust away using a can of "air duster."
- Some fans can be re-lubricated. Generally this is done by peeling off the sticker on one side of the fan hub and dripping a clean, petroleum-free lubricant into the hole(s) beneath. Not all fans benefit from this, though.

Comment: Cleaning the dust helped :)